# I'm getting error while trying to insert values in myslqli database on xampp server

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

> Error: 1
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

here is my code

```
<?php 
require('db_connect.php');

//Code for Registration 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $query="INSERT INTO `user`(`Id`, `name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ('','$name','$email','$password')";
    $msg=mysqli_query($connection,$query);


if ($connection->query($msg) === TRUE)
{
    echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else
{
`enter code here`echo "Error: " . $msg . "<br>" . $connection->error;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1):

what is your sql version ?
you should check if values `$name=$_POST['name'];` return data 
if any of this values accept null in your database